# Objective C - iOS Multiple Table Views

Tags: ios, uitableview

I'm trying to write an app that connects to my web service and displays data in a table view. I also have a static table view for a menu. The static table view works (responds to clicks, shows options, etc.) but I'm stumped on getting the second table view working. There is no more than 1 table view per window. I'll be adding about 10 table views.

Code for static table view:

```
- (UITableViewCell *) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *simpleTableIdentifier = @"dataSelect"; //Name of table view


    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier];

    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier];
    }
    cell.textLabel.text = [tableData objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator;
    return cell;
}
```

tableData is the array that I'm inserting.

Comment: I'm not clear on the difference between what your program is doing vs. what you want it to do.

Comment: Right now, it is displaying 1 table view. I want it to display multiple table views, but I'm not sure how.

Comment: In cellForRowIndexPath, you have to put conditional check against tableview and do the appropriate action there.

Comment: @Idindu What do you mean? I didn't write the code myself, I pulled it from an online tutorial.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
- (UITableViewCell *) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *simpleTableIdentifier = @"dataSelect"; //Name of table view

    if (tableView == tableview1) {
        UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier];

        if (cell == nil) {
            cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier];
        }
        cell.textLabel.text = [tableData objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator;
        return cell;
    } else if (tableview == tableview2) {   

        // do actions related to tableview 2 here

    } else {

         // and so on
    }
```

}